# Possible to disable the content editor on certain page templates in wordpress backend?

Tags: wordpress

I am using the advanced custom fields plugin for wordpress which means some of my pages have defunct content editors in them so I want to disable them on certain pages.  I did find the code below on some websites, but this creates an error in  the backend `Undefined index: post` and `Undefined index: post_ID`

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'hide_editor' );

function hide_editor() {
    // Get the Post ID.
    $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
    if( !isset( $post_id ) ) return;

    // Get the name of the Page Template file.
    $template_file = get_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', true);

    if($template_file == 'contact.php'){ // edit the template name
        remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
    }
}
```

Comment: Well done on spotting the error that no one else seems to come across. Seems very few people developed WordPress sites with debugging enabled. Please mark @NashwanDoaqan 's answer as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use PHP function isset() to fix this erros :

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'hide_editor' );

function hide_editor() {

        // Get the Post ID.
        if ( isset ( $_GET['post'] ) )
        $post_id = $_GET['post'];
        else if ( isset ( $_POST['post_ID'] ) )
        $post_id = $_POST['post_ID'];

    if( !isset ( $post_id ) || empty ( $post_id ) )
        return;

    // Get the name of the Page Template file.
    $template_file = get_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', true);

    if($template_file == 'contact.php'){ // edit the template name
        remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
    }

}
```